# Particular meta tag - viewport - insertion when dealing with plugin

Tags: php, functions, wp-head

I am dealing with a plugin, not with a theme, but what I want is to include this meta in the head section.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
```

I browsed this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Meta_Tags_in_WordPress), but this link is also not helpful.

I believe it is doable through hooks and filter somehow.

w/o this meta tag the content is shrinking, including fonts getting minimized.

Comment: This has no business being part of a plugin. It affects the appearance of the site so is the theme's responsibility. If something like this isn't already in the theme, then it's likely not a responsive theme, and adding this won't fix that.

Comment: If it is not implemented by a theme. It becomes the business of a plugin creator to implement it. Have some empathy before nurturing a tendency to downvote all the time. I hardly remember any post in the past that you have not downvoted. despite the fact that this may be helpful for many in the future.

Comment: It is _not_ the business of a plugin creator to implement anything like this. That's not how that works. This code does nothing useful unless the theme is built to support it, in which case it would already have it.

Comment: I know but you can check here even default 2019 is not supporting → [not supporting](http://html.trafficopedia.com/temp/1/) That's why I said please have some empathy to OP.

Comment: Twenty Nineteen _already has_ that meta tag. It's a responsive theme. The reason stuff is appearing zoomed out is because of your CSS. If you look at the page you'll see that stuff is zoomed out because you have a popover element positioned absolutely over to the right. If you delete the popover element you'll see the issue is fixed.

Comment: Ok Let me have a check, but it also has a [HTML version](http://html.trafficopedia.com/fclients/visa/) where things are not stretching. so why the anomaly? popover element positioned absolutely there also.

Comment: I don't know what the CSS is for your HTML version, but it likely has some sort of wrapper around the site with `overflow: hidden;` that's preventing it from causing this issue. If you're developing this as a plugin that can be use with any theme then you need to add something yourself to take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just use the `wp_head` action for this?
I mean something like this:

```
function add_meta_tags() {
?>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
<?php }
add_action('wp_head', 'add_meta_tags');
```

Should work perfectly.

Comment: I tried a similar thing, but didnt worked. Let me try your code and check my own. Have you ever tested this one.

Comment: Alright - I assume you're writing your own plugin - otherwise I would suggest to add this to the theme functions.php, instead of editing an existing plugin. And yes, I've used wp_head several times to add meta to the head-section. Ex. facebook OG meta etc.

Comment: I am using the default 2019 theme. I am facing the problem [here](http://html.trafficopedia.com/temp/1/)

Comment: I see the viewport is set already.
Although, I would **not** suggest using "minimum-scale" as your might be restricting people who may have a visual impairment.

Comment: Currently I am troubleshooting the issue at hand.

Comment: Alright - let me know if you need anything :)

Comment: I have not tested, but I think your solution will work when such a situation arises.

Comment: Sounds good :) Good luck with the project!

Comment: Once I test your code. I will inform you.

Comment: Goodie - thanks!